# Return dynamic compile time type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've written a method to imitate the Null conditional operator / Elvis operator , including autocomplete **and** array support :

Say I have this object :

```
var o = { a: { b: { c:[{a:1},{a:2}] , s:"hi"} } };
```

I can access the second element in the array and fetch `a` :

```
if ( n(o, (k) => k.a.b.c[1].a) == 2 ) 
 {
    alert('Good'); //true
 }
```

What I've done was to cause the expression to be sent as a function  , which then I can parse as string :

```
function n<T>(o :T , action : (a:T)=>any):any { 
    let s = action.toString().toString().split('return')[1].split('}')[0].split(';')[0];
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); //for  array access
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');    //remove first dot        
    var a = s.split('.');
    for (var i = 1, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {   //i==0 is the k itself  ,aand we dont need it
        var k = a[i];
        if ( o && o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            o = o[k];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

[**It does work**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20o%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20%7B%20c%3A%5B%7Ba%3A1%7D%2C%7Ba%3A2%7D%5D%20%2C%20s%3A%22hi%22%7D%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20n%3CT%3E(o%20%3AT%20%2C%20action%20%3A%20(a%3AT)%3D%3Eany)%3Aany%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20s%20%3D%20action.toString().toString().split('return')%5B1%5D.split('%7D')%5B0%5D.split('%3B')%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%20%3D%20s.replace(%2F%5C%5B(%5Cw%2B)%5C%5D%2Fg%2C%20'.%241')%3B%20%2F%2Ffor%20%20array%20access%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%20%3D%20s.replace(%2F%5E%5C.%2F%2C%20'')%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fremove%20first%20dot%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20a%20%3D%20s.split('.')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%201%2C%20n%20%3D%20a.length%3B%20i%20%3C%20n%3B%20%2B%2Bi)%20%7B%20%20%20%2F%2Fi%3D%3D0%20is%20the%20k%20itself%20%20%2Caand%20we%20dont%20need%20it%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20k%20%3D%20a%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(%20o%20%26%26%20o.hasOwnProperty(k))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20o%20%3D%20o%5Bk%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(%20n(o%2C%20(k)%20%3D%3E%20k.a.b.c%5B1%5D.a)%20%3D%3D%202%20)%20alert('good')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A) as expected , but I have a small problem.

The signature of the method returns `any` :

```
function n<T>(o :T , action : (a:T)=>any) :any 
                                           ^^^
```

**Question:**

Is there any option that the return value will more specific ( or even exact) as the prop I'm trying to access ?

So  `n(o, (k) => k.a.b.c[1].a)` will be `:number`
and    `n(o, (k) => k.a.b.s)` will be `:string`

Is it possible ? if not , is there a way to make return value to be more "typi" ?

---

[Link for comment](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20o%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20%7B%20c%3A%5B%7Ba%3A1%7D%2C%7Ba%3A2%7D%5D%20%2C%20s%3A%22hi%22%7D%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20n%3CT%2C%20TValue%3E(o%3A%20T%2C%20action%3A%20(a%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20TValue)%3A%20TValue%20%7C%20null%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20s%20%3D%20action.toString().toString().split('return')%5B1%5D.split('%7D')%5B0%5D.split('%3B')%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%20%3D%20s.replace(%2F%5C%5B(%5Cw%2B)%5C%5D%2Fg%2C%20'.%241')%3B%20%2F%2Ffor%20%20array%20access%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%20%3D%20s.replace(%2F%5E%5C.%2F%2C%20'')%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fremove%20first%20dot%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20a%20%3D%20s.split('.')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%201%2C%20n%20%3D%20a.length%3B%20i%20%3C%20n%3B%20%2B%2Bi)%20%7B%20%20%20%2F%2Fi%3D%3D0%20is%20the%20k%20itself%20%20%2Caand%20we%20dont%20need%20it%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20k%20%3D%20a%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(%20o%20%26%26%20o.hasOwnProperty(k))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20o%20%3D%20o%5Bk%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cany%3Eo%20%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(%20n(o%2C%20(k)%20%3D%3E%20k.a.b.c%5B1%5D.a)%20%3D%3D%202%20)%20alert('good')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add an extra type parameter for the return value and let the compiler figure out that the type parameter is the return type of the expression:

```
var o = { a: { b: { c: [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }], s: "hi" } } };
function n<T, TValue>(o: T, action: (a: T) => TValue): TValue | null {
    let s = action.toString().toString().split('return')[1].split('}')[0].split(';')[0];
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); //for  array access
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');    //remove first dot        
    var a = s.split('.');
    let result: any = o
    for (var i = 1, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {   //i==0 is the k itself  ,aand we dont need it
        var k = a[i];
        if ( result && result.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            result = result[k];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


let nr = n(o, (k) => k.a.b.c[1].a) // is number | null

var str = n(o, (k) => k.a.b.s) // is string | null
```

**Note** The `|null` part is optional but makes sense in the context of your implementation.

Comment: Thanks! However , I [do have one `any` left at the end](https://i.imgur.com/H12LenP.jpg)...problem is that `o` always has a new type ( in each iteration)  . Can that be fixed ?

Comment: You mean it's completely unknown? If so even the expression is not really checked.. If you provide a full example I can have a look :-)

Comment: I've added a link at the main question at the bottom ( since url is too long to put in comments).

Comment: @RoyiNamir Oh sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you don't know `T` at call site. The `any` in the implementation  is unavoidable. I added the a method body that does not use an assertion, but the `any` is necessary. The call site will be call safe though :)

Comment: Hi - can you please have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053152/creating-tofunc-generic-method-in-typescript) ?