# Creating `toFunc` generic method in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a model in Ts which I need to populate with some properties.

Current code simplification is  :

```
var  claimSummaryDetails :   {
                  Name :  this._store.selectSync("currentUser") 
                                   .Result
                                   .Family
                                   .find(m => m.MemberID == openClaim.Member_ID)
                }
```

Ok. This is where things get complicated.
Please notice that I **don't** have `name` populated yet (with a string) :

[image]

I have an *Object* with many "name" options ( `englishFirstName` / `localfirstName`)

Ok  - so which name should I show ?

Well that's why we have a `lang`  indicator called `isEnglish:boolean`

So basically :

if  `isEnglish ==true` , we should take  :

```
{Name: this._store.selectSync("currentUser")
.Result
.Family
.find(m => m.MemberID == openClaim.Member_ID).englishfirstname}
```

otherwise

```
{Name: this._store.selectSync("currentUser")
.Result
.Family
.find(m => m.MemberID == openClaim.Member_ID).localFirstName}
```

Sure   , I could do this :

```
{Name: isEnglish  ? this._store...........englishFirstName : this._store....localFirstName}
```

But please notice that it scans the store twice and it's way too long.

Ok.

In C# (long time ago) I've created an extension method which allowed me to take the argument and do whatever I want , no matter what type :

```
public static class A
{
    public static Tout ToFunc<T, Tout>(this T obj, Func<T, Tout> f)
    {
        return f(obj);
    }
}

class Person
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    bool isEnglish = true;
    Person[] a = new Person[] { new Person() { Prop1 = 1,Prop2=100 }, new Person() { Prop1 = 2,Prop2=200 }, new Person() { Prop1 = 3,Prop2=300 } };

    Console.WriteLine(a.First().ToFunc(whatever => isEnglish ?whatever.Prop1 : whatever.Prop2 ));

}
```

Result : 1

Please notice this :

```
.ToFunc(whatever => isEnglish ?whatever.Prop1 : whatever.Prop2
```

`whatever` is the value of X in `X.toFunc` and I have access to its props .

this saves me to scan twice the store , and creat additional variables/methods

**Question**

I've tried to do this with TS , but without success :

```
interface Object {
    toFunc(a:(a)=>any): any;
}
Object.prototype.toFunc = function  (f:(a)=>any){
    f();
}


var g= [{a:1,b:2}]
let res= g.find(d => d.a == 1).toFunc((a) => { if (a.a == 1) return 1; else return 2 })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Object%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toFunc(a%3A(a)%3D%3Eany)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AObject.prototype.toFunc%20%3D%20function%20%20(f%3A(a)%3D%3Eany)%7B%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20f()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20g%3D%20%5B%7Ba%3A1%2Cb%3A2%7D%5D%0D%0Ag.find(d%20%3D%3E%20d.a%20%3D%3D%201).toFunc((a)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20if%20(a.a%20%3D%3D%201)%20alert(1)%3B%20else%20alert(2)%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A)

How can I fix my code to support Generics with `.toFunc(a=>a...)` for every type ?

In other words , how can I achieve this :

```
var  claimSummaryDetails :   {
                  Name :  this._store.selectSync("currentUser") 
                                   .Result
                                   .Family
                                   .find(m => m.MemberID == openClaim.Member_ID)
                                   .toFunc(item=>isEnglish ? item.englishFirstName : item.localFirstName)
            }
```

**BTW**

One solution that have crossed my mind is  ( using IIFE) :

```
    {Name: ((customer) => this.isEng 
                             ? customer.englishfirstname 
                             : customer.localfirstname)(
this._store.selectSync("currentUser")                                                                          
.Result
.Family
.find(m => m.MemberID == openClaim.Member_ID))  },
```

But I want to know if it's possible to create a typed `toFunc` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding a method on `Object` should be carefully considered, you can get the types to be inferred if you use a generic parameter for the `this` parameter

```
interface Object {
    toFunc<T, R>(this: T, fn:(a: T)=> R): R;
}
Object.prototype.toFunc = function <T, R> (this:T, f:(a:T)=> R){

    return f(this);

}


var g= [{a:1,b:2}]
var result = g.find(d => d.a == 1).toFunc(i => this.isEng ? i.a : i.b)
```

Comment: What can I say , you're the man (again). BTw I don't see how adding a toFunc to the prototype can do any harm. it's my code , and it's a closed scripts library. so if something will fail , it will fail our tests. Thanks !

Comment: @RoyiNamir if your environment is controlled you should be fine, the problem generally is that you are adding the function to a global object and other libraries may interfere with it.

Comment: BTW [it does work](https://i.imgur.com/JaF8jrG.jpg) - but do you know why it [doesn't complete](https://i.imgur.com/YjVcmp5.jpg) `toFunc` - even though [I did declared it in d.ts](https://i.imgur.com/PcmrGbz.jpg)......(already restarted ide)

Comment: @RoyiNamir not sure why it behaves that way. I tested in the playground and although the method  compiles it isn't suggested there either, would be interesting to investigate but I'm on holiday right now so it'll have to wait for another day :-D. Maybe raise the issue on github.com? Or see if someone else already did

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use getter in typescript, with a conditional statement.
A simple example:

```
class Family {

    isEnglish = false;
    firstName = "FirstName"
    lastName = "LastName"

    constructor(isEnglish: boolean) {
        this.isEnglish = isEnglish;
     }

    get getName(): string{

        if (this.isEnglish) {
            return this.firstName
        } else {
            return this.lastName
        }

    }


}



let family = new Family(true);
alert(family.getName)
```

Comment: Becuase I can't touch Family. Family is a POCO object  for TS that is populated from server schema response. Also Family should not know language , and it shouldn't care about language. (separation of concern)